# get_headers() used on live site is not returning any array but on localhost it is

Tags: php

When I use the function get_headers($url) where `$url = "https://www.example.com/product.php?id=15"` on my live site then it is not returning any array from given url. I get nothing. But when the same code is used on my localhost, I get following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Cache-Control: private
    [2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    [3] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    [4] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wumg0dyscw3c4pmaliwehwew; path=/; HttpOnly
    [5] => X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
    [6] => X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    [7] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    [8] => Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 13:06:18 GMT
    [9] => Connection: close
    [10] => Content-Length: 73867
)
```

So, why the function is not working successfully on live?

**EDIT**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['prdurl']))
{
    $url = $_POST['prdurl'];

    print_r(get_headers($url)); // not getting any array on live but on localhost

    if(is_array(@get_headers($url)))
    {
        // some code goes here...
    }
    else
    {
        echo "URL doesn't exist!"
    }
}

?>
```

One more thing to note down here is that I'm using `file_get_html` to retrieve the html page from the remote url. It's working on my localhost but not on live as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have that function on live?show function code as well as how's you are calling it?

Comment: Does the remote server support `HEAD` requests? Is it filtering based on user agent? It sounds like the request is failing completely, check the remote site's HTTP logs. Your production server might also be firewalled from making outgoing connections.

Comment: @Geoffrey Why does remote server not support `HEAD`? If that happens then I couldn't get any array on my localhost too.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yes I do have that function on live. Please check my EDIT part of question.

Comment: You can configure the HTTP server to reject `HEAD` requests, it might be done for security, or various other reasons. Check the HTTP logs, see if the request is even getting to the server, if it is not it's likely a firewall/network issue.

Comment: @Geoffrey Why there is no problem on localhost? Only on live?

Comment: I uploaded header response pictures there.

Comment: Different server configuration with localhost vs live... again, check the target server!

Comment: @Geoffrey you are not understanding my issue properly. I know localhost is different from live server. The problem is when I am fetching content from live to localhost then its working but when I fetch content from live to live then its not working. I hope it will clear your confusion.

Comment: I completely understand your problem, you are still not performing basic diagnostics to determine where the fault is. I state again, check the servers HTTP logs. If you do not provide diagnostic information how can anyone help you? Clearly there is some difference between your dev and production systems... Your question is like asking "Why doesn't my car start?", there is no one answer without more information.

Comment: @Geoffrey, OK I agree with you. But how to perform basic diagnose for HTTP logs? Can you please guide me?

Comment: That's not what StackOverflow is for, go over and ask how on ServerFault